# How to Implement Blue-Green deployment on Elastic Beanstalk environment using CICD

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am trying to implement the Blue-Green deployment using the CICD pipeline. I am following this guide here:
https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-codepipeline-bluegreen-deployment/doc/blue-green-deployments-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf
Now in this guide on page 16, it is saying to launch the CF template. Then we have to enter some parameters after uploading the template. I am right now using the sample PHP application of aws which is zipped and stored in one of my S3 bucket. Parameters are following:

[image]

**Here elb-blue-green-sample is my bucket where the sample PHP application is zipped and stored. Beanstalk Source Stage S3 Bucket key is pointing to the PHP zip file in my bucket. Every else parameter I keeping blank as they are optional and CF will create it on its own.
Now when I launch this template it is showing following error and is then Rollbacking:**

[image]

Please help me to implement if somebody has implemented it or have any experience as I am stuck here and do not know where I am understanding it wrong.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `Beanstalk Source Stage S3 Bucket key` will be just:

```
php-v1 (1).zip
```

Comment: Hey Marcin, I tried it but it is not working. Showing the same error as above

Comment: @HetulSheth Hi. Maybe the key name (i.e. zip name) is incorrect. Are you sure it exists and has this exact name?. Not sure about spaces in them. I can't comment on the entire solution, just on the use of the wrong key (which had bucket name in it) in the original question.

Comment: I checked it. It is present there with same name.